# ownerDocument property of node is null

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I am working on a Firefox extension in which I am trying to find if a given node intersects the selection range in a web page. For this, I am using the following code:

```
var rangeIntersectsNode = function(range, node) {
        var nodeRange = node.ownerDocument.createRange();
        try {
            nodeRange.selectNode(node);
        }
        catch(e) {
            nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
        }

        return range.compareBoundaryPoints(content.Range.END_TO_START, nodeRange) == -1 &&
        range.compareBoundaryPoints(content.Range.START_TO_END, nodeRange) == 1;
    }
```

When I use this code in Firefox version 9 or lower, I get an error in the console which says `ownerDocument is null`

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here and how I can set it right? Is there an equivalent api for older version of the browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If this property is used on a node that is itself a document, the result is null.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.ownerDocument)

See also:
[Dom 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#node-ownerDoc)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not get this error when I run this code in newer browsers (Firefox 10 and later). I was unable to figure out the reason for this.

Comment: @quad_damage: How about you check nevertheless whether `node` is a document? We don't know why your code works in Firefox 10 (chances are that the reason is outside the code snippet you've shown) but you've got the answer to your question - namely how `node.ownerDocument` can be `null`. It's up to you to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate it further.